# Selecting item in ListBox changes a ComboBox selected item

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form I set a listbox and combobox to the same datasource like this

```
    public DetailsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.categories_comboBox.DataSource = TextSelectionSettings.Default.categories;
        this.categories_listBox.DataSource = TextSelectionSettings.Default.categories;
    }
```

The items I have listed in the collection show up in the listbox and combobox, but when I click an item in the listbox, it changes the selected item in the combobox, and vice versa.  This is not what I expected, because I have no events defined yet for either control.

Is there a way to decouple the two?

**EDIT:** categories is of type

> System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection

and the TextSelectionSettings are ApplicationSettings

Comment: what's the data type of categories?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 StringCollection

Comment: You have bound both to the same datasource, so what do you expect?? You may add one or two `.ToList()` to create copies if you want to have them independent or insert a BindingSource.

Comment: @TaW Why should viewing the datasource have an effect on what is selected?  I'm not changing any data.

Comment: But as you have not added a layer with a 'cursor' both share the 'cursor'. A datasource is more than just the data. - You change the 'cursor' (aka rowpointer)...

Comment: @TaW makes no sense.....when I do the same thing in WPF application the two controls are not coupled in this way, changing one does not affect the other.  I just tried it setting ItemSource for listbox and combobox to the exact same StringCollection in the application settings.  This is the expected behavior.

Comment: So? a) What's got WPF got to do with it? b) It may come handy sometimes. c) Does it work now?

Comment: @TaW an example of how it should work.

Comment: It can work either way, your pick. Knowing the rules is always necessary.

Comment: @TaW agreed, thanks for pointing out that other solution, setting the binding sources independently solved my problem.